# Making query show latest updated

Tags: php, sql

So I have a script that displays all the topics posted with the information about the topic, I was wondering if anybody could help me make it so whenever somebody comments on it or if the post is edited that it will bump it to the first line echod of the query?

```
    function getReplies($id){
        $q = @mysql_query("SELECT reply_content, reply_date, reply_by FROM replies WHERE reply_id='$id'");
        if(!$q){
            echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
        }

        $res = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $q2 = @mysql_query("SELECT `topic_subject` FROM `topics` WHERE `topic_id`='$id'");
        if(!$q2){
            echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
        }

        $res2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2);
        if($_SESSION['id'] == $res['reply_by']){
            echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><b>'.$res2['topic_subject'].'</b></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   '.nl2br($res['reply_content']).'
  </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Posted By <strong><a href="../public.php?id='.$res["reply_by"].'">'.getOwner($res['reply_by']).'</stong></a>
                    on <strong>'.$res['reply_date'].'</strong><br />
                    <a href="edit.php?id='.$id.'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a>
                </div>
</div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            echo'<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><b>'.$res2['topic_subject'].'</b></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   '.nl2br($res['reply_content']).'
  </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Posted By <strong><a href="../public.php?id='.$res["reply_by"].'">'.getOwner($res['reply_by']).'</stong></a>
                    on <strong>'.$res['reply_date'].'</strong><br />
                </div>
</div>
            </div>';
        }

    }
```

Comments:
[image: Comments structure in DB]

Posts:
[image: Posts structure in DB]

Topics:
[image: Topics structure in DB]

Comment: If you mean for that to happen dynamically without the page refreshing, then you will need to use javascript to XHR (AJAX) data from the server and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but for now I want to start simple and just make it so when somebody replies it puts it at the top.

Comment: Looking at your code and trying to optimize it for you but I can't quite see the images you posted for your tables. Can you explain what you're doing here? What does $_SESSION['id'] mean, for example? Also, could you please post your DB relationships in text?

Comment: Try right-clicking the image and opening it in a new tab.

Comment: That helps a little - quick question. Why does reply_id and topic_id use the same $id variable in the function?

Comment: topic_id is the same as reply_id. As reply_id is checking the row of where the content of the post is and topic_id is checking the row of where the title is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39158/discussion-between-francisco-preller-and-kevin-harrison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your first query and grant it an ORDER BY, perhaps?

```
$q = "SELECT   reply_content, reply_date, reply_by
      FROM     replies
      WHERE    reply_id='$id'
      ORDER BY reply_date DESC";
```

It would seem to me also, that you are using two queries, where you only really need to be using one.

**UPDATE: Optimized code, try not to repeat yourself, and join queries**

```
function getReplies($id) {

      $query = "SELECT   replies.reply_content,
                         replies.reply_date,
                         replies.reply_by
                         topics.topic_subject
                FROM     replies,
                         topics
                WHERE    replies.reply_id = topics.topic_id
                  AND    replies.reply_id = '$id' " . //<== PS: You should sanitize this $id parameter
              " ORDER BY replies.reply_date DESC";
                // You can replace the replies.reply_date column by whatever you end up with for sorting

      // Important note - Look into mysqli, mysql is deprecated and too old to be used these days.
      $q = @mysql_query($query);

      if(!$q) {
          echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
      }

      $res = mysql_fetch_array($q);

      $output = '
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading"><b>'.$res['topic_subject'].'</b></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              '.nl2br($res['reply_content']).'
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                Posted By <strong><a href="../public.php?id='.$res["reply_by"].'">'.getOwner($res['reply_by']).'</stong></a>
                on <strong>'.$res['reply_date'].'</strong><br />';

      if($_SESSION['id'] == $res['reply_by'])
        $output .= '<a href="edit.php?id='.$id.'">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a>';

      $output .= '
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>';

      echo $output;

    }
```

Comment: Thankyou! Although how would I make this work for when a new comment appears? Could I order it by the comments datetime field in the database and if there are no comments order by reply_date DESC?

Comment: I was going to say when somebody comments update reply_date to now() but that wouldn't make much sense. What if I added another datetime field and ordered it by that and made it so when you comment it updates that to now()? sounds good?

Comment: Yes, you would use a reply_last_update column or something. I was going to suggest that if that wasn't actually what reply_date was doing. Will try and optimize your code a bit for you too in a second.

Comment: Can we chat about this so we dont spam with comments?